# How is VM_Exit delivered to VM Thread when sending SIGTERM and who does the delivering?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, shutdown-hook

I'm trying to understand how JVM hotspot handles termination signals (`SIGTERM` for example). What I could found is that the `SIGTERM` signal disposition is set [at this point](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/os/posix/jvm_posix.cpp#l84) to `UserHandler` which looks as (comments ommitted):

```
static void UserHandler(int sig, void *siginfo, void *context) {
  if (sig == SIGINT && Atomic::add(1, &sigint_count) > 1) {
    return;
  }
  if (sig == SIGINT && VMError::is_error_reported()) {
    os::die();
  }
  os::signal_notify(sig);
}
```

So all it does is to notify `Signal Dispatcher` and set the received signal number to the [`static volatile jint pending_signals[NSIG+1]`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp#l2489).

But in case of `SIGTERM` the actual `exit(143)` is done in `VM Thread`. The [`VM_Exit`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/runtime/vmOperations.hpp#l470) task with the `_exit_code = 143` is somehow delivered to the `VM Thread`.

**Question:** Can you give a hint who generates this `VM_Exit` task and sends it to `VM Thread` later? I'm particularly concerned about how the 143 is set to `VM_Exit::_exit_code`?

I ran JVM HotSpot under gdb with the following main class:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Shutdown hook is called");
        }));
        Thread.sleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

And did not find that `Signal Dispatcher` was sending the `VM_Exit` task. The termination occured at [that statement](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/runtime/thread.cpp#l1902):

```
JavaCalls::call_virtual(&result,
                        threadObj, thread_klass,
                        vmSymbols::exit_method_name(),
                        vmSymbols::void_method_signature(),
                        THREAD);
```

Comment: I noticed this is not your first question where the title completely mismatches the highlighed question. It's hard to understand whether you are interested in the invocation of shutdown hooks (which is done mostly in Java code) or in calling `VM_Exit` which is done at the late phase of JVM termination when no Java code is longer running.

Comment: @apangin I fixed the title.

Comment: @apangin I found that there is `SIGTERM handler` thread invoking [JVM_Halt](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#l475) with the code 143. But its invocation is done from the JIT compiled code. Can you give an idea which code does the invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGTERM`, `SIGINT` and `SIGHUP` are handled in [Java code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/unix/classes/java/lang/Terminator.java#l51) of `java.lang.Terminator`.

One of the lesser known features of [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) is that it can profile arbitrary native functions and show mixed Java+native stacks. E.g. if you want to intercept `JVM_Halt` and see what Java code calls it, run

```
$ java -agentpath:/path/to/libasyncProfiler.so=start,traces,threads,event=JVM_Halt Main

Started [JVM_Halt] profiling
^CShutdown hook is called
--- 1 events (100.00%), 1 sample
  [ 0] JVM_Halt
  [ 1] java.lang.Shutdown.halt0
  [ 2] java.lang.Shutdown.halt
  [ 3] java.lang.Shutdown.exit
  [ 4] java.lang.Terminator$1.handle
  [ 5] jdk.internal.misc.Signal$1.run
  [ 6] java.lang.Thread.run
  [ 7] [SIGINT handler tid=19080]
```

Comment: Is it possible to see such mixed java/native stacktraces  in `--enable-debug` build? Or some extra configuration is required?

Comment: @SomeName Yes, there are debug functions like [`ps()`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/utilities/debug.cpp#l457) that print Java stack trace under gdb.

Comment: Wow, it prints the exact stacktrace you showed with all addresses. Very cool thing, now it is much easier to understand what is going on when debugging under gdb. Thank you.